# How to detect badminton shuttle from broadcast videos using Ptython OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to detect badminton shuttle from the broadcast badminton videos.
First I tried to identify the badminton court lines using `bitwise_or` mask of white colour as most of the lines are white in colour. 
Then I applied background subtraction function from OpenCV to remove the background noise from the frames.

Below is the result I'm getting from the code I've written:
**Input Frame**[image: Input frame]

**Output Frame**
[image: Output Frame]

I've manually marked the shuttle with a red circle in the images above to make it visible. 

Is there any method by which I can check if the shuttle drops or crosses the lines so that I can verify a point was scored or not?

**Below is the code that I've written to mask and remove background:**

````
import numpy as np
import time

# KNN background subtraction function
subtractor = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorKNN(50,50,0)

#capture video from file
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('../Videos/cropped.mp4')

while(1):

    #reading the video frame by frame
    ret,frame = cap.read()

    if ret:
        frame = cv2.resize(frame,(1366,768)) #resize the frame

        hls = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HLS) #converting the frame to hls color format

        #white mask to detect white lines
        lower_white = np.uint8([0, 200, 0])
        upper_white = np.uint8([255, 255, 255])
        white_mask = cv2.inRange(hls,lower_white,upper_white)

        #yellow mask
        lower_yellow = np.uint8([10, 0, 100])
        upper_yellow = np.uint8([40, 255, 255])
        yellow_mask = cv2.inRange(hls, lower_yellow, upper_yellow)  

        #combining the mask
        mask = cv2.bitwise_or(white_mask, yellow_mask)

        #remove the background from gray frame
        bg_remove = subtractor.apply(gray)

        #combining the result of masking and background removal 
        roi = cv2.bitwise_or(mask,bg_remove)

        #displaying the result
        cv2.imshow('ROI',roi)

    k = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if k == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows```
````

Comment: So you want line detection for the borders of the playing field and object tracking for the badminton shuttle? Is that correct understood?

Comment: yep that's correct

Comment: Well for object tracking you could look into this nice blog post by Adrian Rosebrock: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/07/30/opencv-object-tracking/ And for line detection I would recommend using Hough line transform, more information here: https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html